# SQL access related query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When i am trying to execute the below query:

```
use [msdb]
go
GRANT SELECT ON [sys].[dm_tran_current_transaction] TO 
[User1];
```

I am getting below error:

> Msg 4629, Level 16, State 10, Line 1
>   Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current database is master.

I checked above mentioned view exists under msdb database . Can you please help me with what is the error and why I got this error ?

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server or MS-Access? They are very different things.

Comment: Good starting explanation here (near the bottom applies to your SQL) https://sqlity.net/en/1875/grant-permissions-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can query *Dynamic Management Views* in every database does not necesserily mean that they are defined in every database. Read the error message and do what it says: Use the master database.

Also, granting the user to query the view is not enough, you must also grant the VIEW DATABASE STATE permission to User1 (in the database where the query will be executed).